# angular $resource removes a property when object changes

Tags: angularjs

I've created a Service that returns a $resource

```
module.registerFactory('Website', function ($resource, $cacheFactory) {
        var cache = $cacheFactory('websites');
        var pagedCache = $cacheFactory('websites_paged');
        return $resource('/api/websites/:id', {id: '@id'}, {
            query: {method: 'GET', isArray: false, cache: pagedCache},
            get: {method: 'GET', cache: cache}
        });
    });
```

In an edit state I receive all details by calling

```
$scope.website = Website.get({'id': $stateParams.id});
```

The $scope.website promise contains my data as expected. (Below a shortened JSON result from server)

```
{"id":25,"name":"blabla","url":"http://here.com","description":"blabla",
"tags":[
    {"id":6,"name":"..."},
    {"id":7,"name":"..."}
    {"id":10,"name":"..."}
],
"objectives":[
    {"id":3206,"code":"WIS AD3.c","name":"[ommitted objective 3206]","parent_id":3203},
    {"id":3209,"code":"WIS AD4.b","name":"[ommitted objective 3209]","parent_id":3207}
]}
```

My problem is with the objectives property.
In my EditCtrl I open a modal and send the objectives as selected items to the modal. That works perfect.

```
$scope.selectObjectives = function () {
            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'app/modules/objectives/templates/select-objectives.html',
                controller: 'SelectObjectivesModalCtrl',
                size: 'lg',
                resolve: {
                    selectedItems: function () {
                        return $scope.website.objectives;
                    }
                }
            });
            modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItems) {
                $scope.website.objectives = selectedItems;
                console.log($scope.website);
            });
        }
```

When closing the modal the newly selectedItems are injected back into $scope.website.objectives. (cfr. modalInstance.result.then() ... )
The console logs perfectly all properties - including the objectives.

Now comes the weird part:
As soon as I try to access $scope.website in another function (ie update)
The objectives property is removed from $scope.website.

This is my update method:

```
$scope.updateWebsite = function () {
            console.log($scope.website);
            $scope.website.$save(function () {
                $cacheFactory.get('websites').remove('/api/websites/' + $scope.website.id);
                $cacheFactory.get('websites_paged').removeAll();
                $state.go('app.websites');
            });
        };
```

The console logs all properties in $scope.website - except for the objectives. This is completely removed.

I hope I made myself clear enough.
Thanks for taking some time to help me pointing to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

My bad. 
My response didn't return the entire object as should be in a RESTful POST.